# Среднее арифметическое 2 массивов

Tags: java, android

Есть множественный выбор в приложении android. Нужно, чтобы программа выдавала среднее арифметическое выбранных пользователем позиций.

В первом активити

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener {

Button button_1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


button_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_1);
button_1.setOnClickListener(this);


}

public void onClick(View v) {
switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button_1:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main3Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
}
}
}
```

Во втором активити нужно присвоить переменную типа int ( напр. Uruguay - 3444000. Paraguay - 6725000, и т.д.) элементам списка

```
public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

String[] countries = { "Urugay", "Paraguay", "Jamaica", "Peru", "Mexico"};
Button button2

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

ListView countriesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.countriesList);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, countries);

countriesList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

В общем, нужно рассчитать среднее арифметическое населения стран посредством нажатия button2 (Среднее арифметическое должно отображаться в следующем активити)

Список со странами отображается во втором активити с возможностью множественного выбора. А вот среднее арифметическое после выбора стран, отображается в третьем активити

Нужен совет либо пример кода

Comment: А откуда берутся данные о населении?

Comment: В том и вопрос каким образом скорелировать количество народа и названий  стран

Comment: @Serj А дальше ?

Comment: Вот класс class Country {
        String name;
        int population;

        Country(String name, int population){
            this.name = name;
            this.population = population;
        }
    } Осталось Адаптер переписать и все

Comment: @Serj Тогда как сделать лист из поля с множественным выбором ?

Comment: к сожалению ваш код написан настолько "наколенке", что глаза режет. У вас нарушены все технологии разработки. Извините, но отвечать на этот вопрос, все равно что мертвому припарки делать. Перепишите ваш код по канонам

Comment: @Георгий Чеботарев Только учусь.

Comment: я не хочу вас обидеть, учитесь -это хорошо. но старайтесь учиться на реальных примерах

Answer (score 0):

Для реализации вашей идеи вам нужен другой адаптер. Более функциональный, с ViewHolder-ом, Listener-ом. Тогда можно будет обрабатывать клики по item в RecyclerView, получать данные из item-ов. Смотрите примеры отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick . Я позволю себе привести ссылку на мой проект https://github.com/georrge1994/phoenix Здесь есть достаточно кол-во адаптеров и viewHolder. Проект написан на котлине, но идеи почерпнуть отсюда можно. Ищите адаптеры, как они связаны с layouts и viewholder, и как это все инициализируется и работает. Данные проект - исходный код без ключей к firebase, поэтому у вас не получиться его скомпилировать/отдебажить. Но посмотреть, как это работает можно - скачав приложеньку отсюда: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.phoenix.kspt.develop (это не самореклама, я просто пытаюсь помочь)